# Как правильно выстроить рабочую среду? Git, Vagrant, phpstorm и тд

Tags: git, phpstorm, веб-программирование, vagrant, workflow

Привык работать сразу на сервере продакшена. Но теперь часто сталкиваюсь с серьезными проектами, задачами, битриксом и тд. Хочется научиться делать как положено. Разрабатывать локально, тестить, заливать в продакшн через git. Мануалы в сети все по кусочкам и сложно собрать пазл. Опишите пожалуйста по шагам этапы построения рабочей среды. Начало такое: появляется клиент, сайт на сервере. Допустим надо кардинально доработать. Какие действия?

Мое видение на словах: залить код сайта в git, залить копию локально на виртуалку (видимо vagrant). Все это связать между собой. Разрабатывать локально в phpstorm например. Потом коммитить через гит в продакшн. Верно?

Попутный вопрос: как в этом случае настроить xDebug в PhpStorm для отладки на виртуальной машины? Когда создаю проект там есть опции, удаленная машина, локальная и тд. Но виртуалка это ведь по сути "удаленная"? Но тогда он пытается скопировать все локально. Может посоветуете какой-то видео-курс типа linda.com или книгу/статью.

Comment: несколько абсолютно не связанных «вопросов», часть из которых является просьбой написать несколько руководств. задавайте, пожалуйста, **конкретные** вопросы. **по одному** (с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы).

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле связанный. Написать в общих чертах пошагово как происходит доработка существующего веб-проекта.

Comment: Согласен с @DmitryMorozov. Просто вопрос не на пару предложений.

Comment: Не согласен. Здесь два слабосвязанных вопроса: (а) как использовать git в PHP-проектах, когда дан только production-сервер; (б) как заставить PhpStorm воспринимать проект в Vagrant, как локальный (отладчик, исходный код). И есть в целом верные соображения (о том, как выглядит использование git), которые в комментариях не нуждаются. Так что вопрос стоит разделить.

Comment: @D-side, речь о построении правильного workflow. Да, изначально дан только продакшн. Значит надо 1) поставить туда гит 2) клонировать локально проект 3) добавить его в phpstorm (основной затык тут был потому что долго шла индексация и многие настройки деплоя не появлялись) 4) кодить, коммитить в отдельную ветку локально, мержить с мастером, пушить на тестовый сервер, и затем мержить с продакшеном. С вагрантом уже почти разобрался, надо лишние папки убрать при создании машины типа cgi-bin и html. Проект то в корне лежит.

Comment: Ну вот это первый вопрос: типичный workflow. А второй, о совмещении Vagrant с PhpStorm, это второй. Но я так понимаю, с этим уже почти покончено и эту часть можно убрать из вопроса, оставив достаточно "самодостаточный" вопрос.

Comment: @D-side, верно. Уже и с первым почти покончено если честно. Пока ждал нагуглил всякого разного. Но лучше бы конечно все равно расписали процесс. Еще бы аналог гита под mysql найти, уверен что есть.

Comment: Хм? Версионировать **данные** в MySQL? Или схему (таблицы, индексы...)?

Comment: @D-side, ну полностью базу. Все изменения в ней. Допустим modx хранит чанки, шаблоны в бд. Поменял что либо и как быть?

Comment: Т. е. всё состояние базы. Звучит как задача для Docker + любого менеджера томов для данных, работающего на манер git (Flocker, Convoy, OpenStorage?). Я сам пока в этой области только осваиваюсь и "твёрдых подсказок" у меня пока нет.

Comment: @D-side, немного погуглив нашел такое: https://phinx.org/ и https://code.google.com/archive/p/mysql-php-migrations/ и http://laravel.su/docs/5.0/migrations

Comment: Это миграции не для данных, насколько я знаю. Только для схемы/структуры базы.

Comment: @D-side тогда http://blgo.ru/blog/2013/04/23/git-mysql-backup/

Comment: Ага. В конце поста: *"Не следует использовать подобные кривые велосипеды! Поставьте себе лучше какую-нибудь систему."* У автора нет иллюзий на счёт стабильности этой системы %)